# Proving (A → -A) → -A In a Hilbert system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Trying to prove (A → -A) → -A with the following axioms:

A → (B → A)

(A → (B → C)) → ((A → B) → (A → C))

(-A → -B) → (B → A)

Not an axiom, but you can also use A → (-A → B), which I've already managed to prove it.

Intuitively the proposition makes sense, but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: @KennyLau Then it would be straight forward.  $${1.~A\to(\neg A\to \bot):\textsf{theorem 1}\\2.~ (A\to(\neg A\to \bot))\to((A\to\neg A)\to (A\to \bot)):\textsf{axiom 2}\\3.~(A\to\neg A)\to(A\to \bot):\textsf{modus ponens}}$$

Comment: @KennyLau No, ¬A is not really defined in any way, it's just known to be   a unary operator which satisfies the 3rd axiom.

Comment: This problem can get solved quickly with the use of William McCune's Prover9.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

With Ax.1 and Ax.2 you have to derive some preliminary useful results :

> $\vdash A \to A$ and the derived rule *Syll* : $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$,

and eventually the *Deduction Theorem*.

Then, Ax.3 is crucial in deriving double negation laws:

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \to A$ and : $\vdash A \to \lnot \lnot A$.

Double negation, in turn, give us : $\vdash (A \to B) \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$.

---

Two further *Lemma* :

1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$ --- Ax.1

2) $\vdash (\lnot B \to \lnot A) \to (A \to B)$ --- Ax.3

> (A) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *Syll*

---

1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)$ --- *Lemma* (A)

2) $\vdash (\lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to B))$ --- Ax.2

3) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $\vdash (\lnot A \to \lnot B) \to (B \to A)$ --- Ax.3

> (B) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (B \to A)$ --- from 3) and 4) by *Syll*

---

1) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$ --- *Lemma* (B)

2) $\vdash ((\lnot A \to A) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)) \to (((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A))$ --- Ax.2

3) $\vdash ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)$ --- from $\vdash A \to A$ above

> (C) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to A$ --- from 3) and 4) by *MP*.

---

---

Now the proof :

1) $\vdash (\lnot \lnot A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A$ --- *Lemma* (C)

2) $A \to \lnot A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot \lnot A \to \lnot A$ --- from 2)

4) $\lnot A$ --- from 1) and 3) by *MP*

> > 5) $\vdash (A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A$ --- from 2) and 4) by *DT*, discharging [a].